# Is it possible to establish an HTTPS connection and embed JavaMail inside of it?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, httpurlconnection

What I have here is remote users connecting to an Exchange server via Outlook. What they are literally doing is connecting to a proxy server over an HTTPS connection, using SSL, and then accessing the Exchange.

As a network guy, I know about encapsulation and transparency. Is it possible to open up an HttpURLConnection (HttpsURLConnection) to the proxy and then run my normal, standard issue JavaMail through that? Basically, open the connection to the Proxy server and then, while that connection is open, treat just as if I was connecting directly to an Exchange.

I know that JavaMail does not have the ability to go through a proxy by itself, that's why I am involving HttpURLConnection.

If this is not the standard practice for this particular setup, could someone shine some light on alternatives?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible, but you'll need to write your own [SocketFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/SocketFactory.html) and configure JavaMail to use it.  The SocketFactory will need to make the connection through the HTTP proxy server using the HTTP CONNECT protocol command, then turn the socket over to JavaMail for use.  You'll probably need to write the HTTP protocol support yourself, rather than using HttpURLConnection.

Alternatively, there are some programs that act as a SOCKS proxy server and forward messages through a web proxy server.  You can then use the SOCKS support in JavaMail.

Comment: I wanted to see what my option are. What they pass for IT with my company is unreliable, at best. Have you ever used SOCKS before?

Comment: Yes, I've used SOCKS.

Comment: After doing some research, I found that what I am trying to do is exactly what SOCKS sets out to do. At work, we use HTTPS to a proxy server and the proxy divvies and dumps what it gets from there, including access to the Exchange server.

Now, why did you say that I would need to write my own HTTP protocol myself? The socket should strip all information from the headers, HTTP information included, and leave me with my Java info. It should be transparent, right?

Comment: SOCKS is a completely different protocol for a different kind of proxy server.  It has nothing to do with HTTP.  Your web/HTTP proxy server probably doesn't support SOCKS.  Your company might also have a SOCKS proxy server.  If not, see above.

Comment: My apologies. I am not familiar with SOCKS. I figured it was just a simple way of establishing a socket on the server to use with a remote connection.

Comment: There's more to it than that.

Comment: is using SOCKS the only way to Java app information across the web and through a proxy?

Comment: You need to be more precise than "a proxy".  SOCKS is a general protocol to route connections through a special proxy server.  There are also special-purpose HTTP proxy servers that use a different protocol that only works with HTTP.  I'm not going to give you a complete tutorial on these network protocols in this comment box.  Java supports both types of proxy servers, in different ways, which is why an HTTP proxy server doesn't "just work" for an IMAP or SMTP connection.

Comment: No kidding. I'm more of an app developer and my experience with web communications is limited. I have a strong networking infrastructure engineering and domain/client-side administration knowledge base though. However, that doesn't help much with HTTP. Also, as for programming, I'm still very new to it. I taught myself for the past 2 months as a hobby.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative method, you can also connect directly to an exchange server providing EWS and use JavaMail as you would, by using [javamail4ews](http://javamail4ews.sourceforge.net/getting_started.html%20javamail4ews)